# Why am I not able to preview menu for navigation drawer properly?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a navigation drawer and for that a menu. But it is not showing as required(like a list from left side).
Below is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/drawer_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/drawer_profile_icon"
            android:title="@string/drawer_profile"/>



    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/drawer_action">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/drawer_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_power_settings_new_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/log_out"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/drawer_refresh"
                android:icon="@drawable/drawer_refresh"
                android:title="@string/drawer_refresh"/>
        </menu>
    </item>



</menu>
```

[image: Result in preview]

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the project?

Comment: yes, did not work.

Comment: Android studio sometimes throws ide errors when rendering some interfaces, you would see a red icon on the bottom right of the screen click on it and check the errors ther

Comment: There are no errors in event logs or anywhere. I am not able to know how those menu will look. I tried removing the  'tools:showIn="navigation_view' part but it is showing the drop down kinda version.

Comment: You should migrate to androidx and try new material design library.